# Convert Long to String in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

What am I missing here?

```
var timestamp = (System.currentTimeMillis() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())
String time = Long.toString(time) // Error: Expecting an element
value.setText("" + time)
```

Comment: If you're writing Java, you're missing semicolons.

Comment: Sorry. I found out i was using Kotlin in android studio

Comment: Shouldn’t it be Long.toString(timestsmp) ?

Comment: The `String time =` declaration doesn't look much like Kotlin, either…

Answer (score 3):

You could use *Kotlin* `String` templates:

```
val time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()) / 1000*60*60
value.setText("$time")
```

Otherwise you'd use the `time.toString()` directly.